# Firefox won't show a second alert dialog with Selenium

Tags: unit-testing, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox-22

My code looks like:

```
getDriver().findElement(By.id("ok_button")).click();
new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), 5).until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
assertTrue(isAlertPresent());
Alert alert = getDriver().switchTo().alert();
assertTrue(alert.getText().equals("Please select a group"));
alert.accept();


dialogBox.setRefVariable(inputId, "group1");
getDriver().findElement(By.id("ok_button")).click();
new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), 5).until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
```

The first alert shows and is correctly accepted, but the second alert won't show. I get an error on the last line because, after 5 seconds, the alert isn't present. When I debug the code and manually click the button, the alert still won't show. Even when I open the console on the firefox window and manually enter just "alert("..")", nothing pops up.

I'm using FireFox22 and Selenium 2.31

edit: Problem appears to be the line containing `setRefVariable` (our own code). Removing the line allows everything to work.

edit: Our code ends up calling Selenium.type, which causes Selenium to execute some code which overrides the native alert function... why????

Comment: Does the second alert have focus assigned to it like you did with `.switchTo()` on the first one?

Comment: The second alert never shows, so I can't switch to it